# Giving arguments why polynomials and matrices are or are not vector spaces

Tags: matrices, polynomials, vector-spaces

I have to give arguments why polynomials and matrices are or are not vector spaces, if they are finitely generated and I have to give a basis.

(for example: The set of all polynomials in one variable x. or The set of all polynomials of degree less than or equal to some fixed value n., ... )

Furthermore, I do not quite get if a matrix or polynomial is a vector space. I have always thought square matrices and diagonal ones are a vector space for sure.

I know the typical arguments (has to include the zero vector, addition and multiplication are possible), but how do I know for sure and how to find out about the finitely  generated and basis.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Do you know what finitely generated means? How about a basis?

Comment: I understand the definitions, but Idk, apparently I still have some problems understandin them.

Comment: Ok. Now, to answer your question, it depends on what you want: rigorously proving that certain sets of polynomials or matrices can be thought of as vector spaces when equipped with the right operations requires you to prove all the stuff you mentioned (and some other things). "giving arguments" to me sounds like proving or make plausible a subset of that stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Both examples follow this abstract construct:

Let $X$ be a set and $F$ a field (for instance, $F=\mathbb R$).

Then the set of all functions $X \to F$ form a vector space over $F$, with vector addition and scalar multiplication defined pointwise:

$(f+g)(x) = f(x)+g(x)$

$(\lambda f)(x) = \lambda (f(x))$

The dimension of this vector space is the cardinality of $X$.
A basis is given by Kronecker deltas: $\delta_t(x)= 1$ if $x=t$ and $\delta_t(x)= 0$ if $x\ne t$.
In particular, it has finite dimension iff $X$ is finite.

This construct gives all the examples and more:

- For $m \times n$ matrices, take $X=\{1,2,\dots,m\}\times\{1,2,\dots,n\}$.
- For polynomials of degree at most $n$, take $X=\{0,1,2,\dots,n\}$.
- For formal power series, take $X=\mathbb N$.
- For polynomials of arbitrary degree, take $X=\mathbb N$ and the *subspace* formed by the functions having finite support, that is, that are zero except for a finite number of points in $X$.