# Is it possible to determine what's the field in this vector space?

Tags: number-theory, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, algebraic-number-theory

I was reading through a problem in number theory, and I came across the following vector space:

"Let $V$ be the vector space of all functions $f:(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})^\times \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$"

Where $N$ is a positive multiple of 4. The question was about the eigenvectors of a specific set of linear operators, and that's where my question arose. **From what field should I take the scalars in this vector space?**

No more information is given about this vector space. I believe the most obvious choice is $\mathbb{C}$, because it's the codomain of the functions. I also strongly believe that any subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ is a valid set of scalars, I see no reason why not. Considering no more information is given, is there a good reason for me not to consider $\mathbb{C}$ the set of scalars in this vector space?

If it's of use, the question asked about the simultaneous eigenvector and it's respective eigenvalues of the set of operators defined below:

For each prime $p$, let $T_p: V \rightarrow V$ be:
$$(T_pf)(n) = \bigg\{\begin{array}{l}
f(pn), \text{ if } p\nmid N\\
0, \text{ if } p\mid N\end{array} $$

Comment: I agree:  if not specified otherwise, it is pretty much certain that they meant a vector space over $\mathbb C$.  But it is true that any vector space over $\mathbb C$ is also a vector space over any subfield of $\mathbb C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One very good reason to choose $\mathbb C$ is that it is the simplest and obvious choice that makes the statement true.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1489234/589.