# How do I argue that V is a real vector space with the usual mathematical operations for polynomials?

Tags: linear-algebra

$V = \{p(x) = ax^2 + bx + c : a, b, c \in \mathbb{R} \}$ the set of all polynomials of degree less than or equal to 2. How do I argue that $V$ with the usual mathematical operations for polynomials is a real vector space?

I have found on wiki those requirements in the definition of a vector space.

1. Multiplying a degree 2 polynomial or adding two degree 2 polynomials both result in a degree 2 polynomial, so it's closed.
2. Addition is associative
3. Addition is commutative
4. $0+p(x)=p(x)$
5. $1 \times p(x)=p(x)$
6. $p(x)+(-p(x))=0$
7. Scalar multiplication is associative
8. $a(p(x)+q(x))=ap(x)+aq(x)$
9. $(a+b)p(x)=ap(x)+bp(x)$

But I don't know how to do it?

Comment: Note that in (1), the sum of two degree-$2$ polynomials is a polynomial of degree $\leq 2$, but not necessarily $2$.

Comment: Closure is only required under addition and scalar multiplication. Multiplication of polynomials does not close the set, but that is immaterial to it's vector space properties. Nevertheless, please edit your question.

Comment: For each requirement you have to take polynomials from your set and verify the operation. You may have another option: if you know that $V$ is a subset of another vector space (e.g. the space of all polynomials or real functions) you only have to check the subspace criterion.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, let $X$ be a set and $F$ a field.
Then the set of all functions $X \to F$ form a vector space over $F$, with vector addition and scalar multiplication defined pointwise:

$(f+g)(x) = f(x)+g(x)$

$(\lambda f)(x) = \lambda (f(x))$

The axioms for vector space hold essentially because they hold for $F$.

For polynomials of degree at most $n$, take $X=\{0,1,2,\dots,n\}$.

In you case, $n=2$ and $F=\mathbb R$.

Comment: Adapted from http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1489234/589.